# N1QL convert date into string date format ,Couchbase

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I'm trying to execute query to show date like 01 Jan, 1970. I have this format date 1970-01-01 in Couchbase.I have used

```
DATE_FORMAT_MILLIS(STR_TO_MILLIS('1970-01-01')
```

I need query to execute and show date like 01 Jan, 1970. I have this format date 1970-01-01 in Couchbase.

Comment: I have used DATE_FORMAT_MILLIS(STR_TO_MILLIS('1970-01-01')

Answer (score 1):

You may need CB 7.1

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT_STR('1970-01-01', "%d %b, %Y");
```

https://issues.couchbase.com/browse/DOC-8704

Comment: #vsr 
above query has give  error :
[
  {
    "code": 3000,
    "msg": "syntax error - line 2, column 116, near '_date, \"%d %b, %Y\");', at: as (reserved word)"
  }
]

Comment: what version of couchbase using. can u paste whole query